# How do I assign variables with values from a list?

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I am running this code:

```
int key = 25;
String query = "Select one, two, three, four, five from myTable where key=?";
List<Map<String,Object>> data = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, new Object[]{key});

//one is string, two is int, three is character, four is double, five is string
String one = null;
int two = 0;
char three = '\u0000';
double four = 0.0;
String five = null;
```

I want to set the five variables above with the values returned in the list. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't actually used `JDBCTemplate`, but according to [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29), `queryForList` will return a [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)s, with the keys in each `Map` being the names of the columns.

So to assign those variables from the *first* returned row:

```
Map<String,Object> row = data.get(0);
String one  = (String)row.get("one");

//these will not work -- Integer, Double incompatible with String
/* int two     = ((Integer)row.get("two")).intValue();
double four = ((Double)row.get("four")).doubleValue(); */

//correct method
int two     = Integer.parseInt((String)row.get("two"));
double four = Double.parseDouble((String)row.get("four"));

char three  = ((Character)row.get("three")).charValue();
    String five = (String)row.get("five");
```

As you can see, for the object types, you should just be able to cast. For the primitives, I've cast to the object equivalent and then used that object equivalent's method for getting the underlying primitive (so for `int`, cast to [`Integer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) and then use [`intValue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue%28%29)).

Comment: two = (int)row.get("two") will throw error. As the value is an Object. Object to int parsing is not valid.

Comment: @Nikunj: Thanks, you were reading the first copy of the post, which in my early-morning brain was relying on autoboxing. But autoboxing didn't apply here, so I fixed it. :-)

Comment: @T. J. Crowder: Thanks.. it worked.. posted the answer on ranch also with credits to you :) :)

Comment: @Nikunj: Thanks. I think the need to actually parse the integer and such would depend on the definition of the columns in your table. I would expect an `INT` column to come through as an `Integer` (otherwise, `queryForList` could be defined to just return a `List<Map<String,String>>` rather than `List<Map<String,Object>>`).